# paramiko SSHClient sudo to new user

Tags: python

Need to sudo su - diffuser after connection via SSHClient function.

I cannot login with ssh directly to the required user id in order to run commands owned by that required user.  When at the local cli of the target ssh system, I simply run sudo su - diffuser, and then run the required commands.

Is there anyway to simulate this using the Paramiko SSHClient commands?

Comment: If you run commands out of the context of a shell-session, the "sudo" won't stick. You can use `sudo -u diffuser {actualcommand}` to run a command as a specific user.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're encountering? In my previous comment, I assumed that the second command didn't work, since you are out of sudo context. But maybe you have a different problem?

Comment: the sudo -u diffuser won't work for me because I need to type in my current user password in order to execute the command, either locally or remotely with ssh.

Comment: So then, you'll need to wire your terminal into the output of the process. I'll check with a colleague who knows how to do this with gnome-terminal. Maybe some of the principles are usable for Paramiko. By the way, does `sudo su - diffuser` not need any password? Because if so, you could also set it up to allow `sudo -u diffuers` not to need any password.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this using the SSHClient's invoke_shell method and associated methods (x.send, x.recv, etc.)